# Using <sup> tag for required form fields--good idea?

Tags: css, html, accessibility

Is it a good idea to use `<sup>` tag for required * fields in a form instead of `margin-top: -xnumberofpx`.

```
<label for="address1" required>Address line 1<sup><img src="/src/images/requiredAsterix.png" width="10" height="10" alt="Required!" /><sup></label>
<input type="text" id="address1" name="address1" size="50" ng-maxlength="50" required>
```

[image: Rendering]

Comment: A good idea from what perspective? Accessibility? Maintainability?

Comment: @ Álvaro González -- both Accessibility and Maintainability. I have always seen people using <span> and margin-top to align

Comment: `<sup>` is not a problem here. The bad idea is to use an image instead of text for a simple asterisk. This is a really useless HTTP request...

Comment: i know img is a bad idea. but we have to match with the client's existing pages:\

Comment: So your client does not want you to use `<sup>*</sup>` with a bit of CSS?

Comment: `&#8432;` or  `\20f0` is  ⃰

Comment: Avoid using semantic elements for styling purposes. Use CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The use of the `sup` element, here, is plainly acceptable according to the definition of this tag which is designed to natively indicate superscript elements.
2. The use of an image with a `alt="required"` is perfectly acceptable as this is a perfect way to add an alternative description for people not using screenreaders. Although it's not perfect. The `required` attribute on the element would not be sufficient enough to give this information to standard users without the help of a third-party screenreader.
3. Remove the `required` attribute on the `label` element and close correctly your `sup` tag.
4. The contrast in the inputbox does not satisfy WCAG contrast requirements.
5. The alternative text "Adress line 1" does not seem to be explicit enough but the context may help.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine to add more information to a label if it helps explain the related input. In the HTML spec example, they even use the `<small />` element to show the user the expected format.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element

```
<label>Full name: <input name=fn> <small>Format: First Last</small></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

From an accessibility standpoint, it is redundant to use `alt="required"` and to specify the HTML `required` attribute on the input field.  A screen reader is going to announce it twice.  Set `alt=""` on the image instead.

PS - I assume it is a typo, but the `required` attribute is not valid on the `<label>` tag.